# How can I modify table row height in Google Slides?

Tags: google-slides

In Google Slides, is there an option to modify the row height in a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the cursor and dragging the border lines of a cell.

[image: resize]

As mentioned on the [official Google support page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1696711):

> Resize a row or column
>
> 1. On your computer, open a document or presentation.
> 2. In your table, move your cursor over the gridline of a row or column.
> 3. When your cursor becomes a two-sided arrow, click and drag until the row or column is the size you want.
>
> Make all rows and columns the same size
>
> 1. On your computer, open a document or presentation.
> 2. Right-click a table.
> 3. Click `Distribute rows` or `Distribute columns`.

***Extra Tip***: Minimization of a row is restricted by font size.
That means that a row of fonts sized 48 will not be able to get "shrunk" as much as another one having fonts sized 10.

Answer (score 7):

The way to do this more consistently is to select the whole table, reduce the size of the font as desired and then go to *Format* / *Format Options*.
Then under *Text Fitting* alter the Top and Bottom Padding, which will then narrow or increase the height of the table rows so that it fits on your slide.

This is the only method I've found that is similar to the Row Height Option in PowerPoint.

Answer (score 2):

Just shrink the font size to minimal and then drag the table together. Once done just revert the font size and it will allow you to have smaller row sizes than before. Ugly hack but it does the job.